# Custom background image for navigation bar - sizing and back button colouring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, customization

Before I meet my designers I need to know the sizing for the navigation bar for an iPhone, do I have to supply two images, one high resolution one low ? How does the back button work, how is the colour chosen for that?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At non-retina display, the navigation bar is 320x44px in portrait mode. In landscape it is 480x32.

The back button colour is based on the `tintColor` property for the `UINavigationBar`

If you are setting a background image (using `- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics`), you should create an image for your supported orientations at both standard and retina resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

You do not necesarily need to supply a high resolution and a low resolution image, this is optional but recommended.
The high resolution imagery is for retina displays, which can pack more pixels on a square inch than their predecessors.

Imagine navigation on an iphone like having a stack of cards.
Every new view you open, puts a card on top of the stack.
The back button simply takes the top card off the stack.

The color can be assigned specifically, in fact the look of the button can be changed completely (though this is not recommended)

You can find apple's recommended sizes for the gui elements [in this map](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html).
The sizes here are expressed in `pt` units rather than pixels, but a bit of math can sort that out.

If you need to know the screen size for the pre-retina screens and the retina ones, you can [find those here.](http://www.iphoneresolution.com/)

Comment: Do you know the resolutions for retina and standard iphone screen navigation bars? I'm guessing I can change them, but I'd like to keep the size of the standard one.